# I've a issue my react login page and router code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a form page written in react and typescript and this page works using JWT tokens on the API side. There is no problem on the container page, but on the index.tsx page where the routers are located, I get an error like this:

```
TypeScript error in C:/Users/yusuf/Desktop/ncmaz/src/routers/index.tsx(88,21):
Type 'ConnectedComponent<FC<PageLoginProps>, Omit<PageLoginProps, "login">>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<Object>'.
  Type 'ConnectedComponent<FC<PageLoginProps>, Omit<PageLoginProps, "login">>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<Object>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'PropsWithChildren<Object>' has no properties in common with type 'Omit<PageLoginProps, "login">'.  TS2322
```

I couldn't figure out if the parameters I gave are wrong or there is another problem because everything else seems fine.

> This is my `PageLogin.tsx` File

```
import LayoutPage from "components/LayoutPage/LayoutPage";
import React, { FC, useState } from "react";
import facebookSvg from "images/Facebook.svg";
import twitterSvg from "images/Twitter.svg";
import googleSvg from "images/Google.svg";
import Input from "components/Input/Input";
import ButtonPrimary from "components/Button/ButtonPrimary";
import NcLink from "components/NcLink/NcLink";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import {login} from "actions/auth"

export interface PageLoginProps {
  className?: string;
  e?: any;
  email?: string;
  password?: string | number;
  login?:any;
}

const loginSocials = [
  {
    name: "Continue with Facebook",
    href: "#",
    icon: facebookSvg,
  },
  {
    name: "Continue with Twitter",
    href: "#",
    icon: twitterSvg,
  },
  {
    name: "Continue with Google",
    href: "#",
    icon: googleSvg,
  },
];

const PageLogin: FC<PageLoginProps> = ({ className = "" }:any, {login}:any) => {
  const [formData, setFormdata] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: ""
  })

  const {email, password} = formData;

  const onChange = (e:any) => setFormdata({...formData, [e.target.value]: e.target.value});

  const onSubmit = (e:any) => {
    e.preventDefault();;

    login(email, password);
  };
  

  return (
    <div className={`nc-PageLogin ${className}`} data-nc-id="PageLogin">
      <Helmet>
        <title>Login || Blog Magazine React Template</title>
      </Helmet>
      <LayoutPage
        subHeading="Welcome to our blog magazine Community"
        headingEmoji=""
        heading="Login"
      >
        <div className="max-w-md mx-auto space-y-6">
          <div className="grid gap-3">
            {loginSocials.map((item, index) => (
              <a
                key={index}
                href={item.href}
                className="nc-will-change-transform flex w-full rounded-lg bg-primary-50 dark:bg-neutral-800 px-4 py-3 transform transition-transform sm:px-6 hover:translate-y-[-2px]"
              >
                <img
                  className="flex-shrink-0"
                  src={item.icon}
                  alt={item.name}
                />
                <h3 className="flex-grow text-center text-sm font-medium text-neutral-700 dark:text-neutral-300 sm:text-sm">
                  {item.name}
                </h3>
              </a>
            ))}
          </div>
          {/* OR */}
          <div className="relative text-center">
            <span className="relative z-10 inline-block px-4 font-medium text-sm bg-white dark:text-neutral-400 dark:bg-neutral-900">
              OR
            </span>
            <div className="absolute left-0 w-full top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 border border-neutral-100 dark:border-neutral-800"></div>
          </div>
          {/* FORM */}
          <form className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-6" onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
            <label className="block">
              <span className="text-neutral-800 dark:text-neutral-200">
                Email address
              </span>
              <Input
                type="email"
                placeholder="example@example.com"
                className="mt-1"
                name='email'
                value={email}
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                required
              />
            </label>
            <label className="block">
              <span className="flex justify-between items-center text-neutral-800 dark:text-neutral-200">
                Password
                <NcLink to="/forgot-pass" className="text-sm">
                  Forgot password?
                </NcLink>
              </span>
              <Input type="password" 
                     className="mt-1"
                     name="email"
                     value={password}
                     onChange={e => onChange(e)} />
            </label>
            <ButtonPrimary type="submit">Continue</ButtonPrimary>
          </form>

          {/* ==== */}
          <span className="block text-center text-neutral-700 dark:text-neutral-300">
            New user? {` `}
            <NcLink to="/signup">Create an account</NcLink>
          </span>
        </div>
      </LayoutPage>
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(null, {login})(PageLogin);
```

> and this is my `index.tsx` file which include page routers

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Page } from "./types";
import store from "app/store";
import ScrollToTop from "./ScrollToTop";
import Footer from "components/Footer/Footer";
import Page404 from "containers/Page404/Page404";
import PageArchive from "containers/PageArchive/PageArchive";
import PageAuthor from "containers/PageAuthor/PageAuthor";
import PageSearch from "containers/PageSearch/PageSearch";
import PageSingle from "containers/PageSingle/PageSingle";
import PageSingleHasSidebar from "containers/PageSingle/PageSingleHasSidebar";
import PageSingleTemplate2 from "containers/PageSingle/PageSingleTemp2";
import PageSingleTemp2Sidebar from "containers/PageSingle/PageSingleTemp2Sidebar";
import PageSingleTemplate3 from "containers/PageSingle/PageSingleTemp3";
import PageSingleTemp3Sidebar from "containers/PageSingle/PageSingleTemp3Sidebar";
import PageAbout from "containers/PageAbout/PageAbout";
import PageContact from "containers/PageContact/PageContact";
import PageLogin from "containers/PageLogin/PageLogin";
import PageSignUp from "containers/PageSignUp/PageSignUp";
import PageForgotPass from "containers/PageForgotPass/PageForgotPass";
import PageDashboard from "containers/PageDashboard/PageDashboard";
import PageSubcription from "containers/PageSubcription/PageSubcription";
import HeaderContainer from "containers/HeaderContainer/HeaderContainer";
import PageHome from "containers/PageHome/PageHome";
import PageHomeDemo2 from "containers/PageHome/PageHomeDemo2";
import PageHomeDemo3 from "containers/PageHome/PageHomeDemo3";
import PageAuthorV2 from "containers/PageAuthor/PageAuthorV2";
import PageHomeDemo4 from "containers/PageHome/PageHomeDemo4";
import PageSearchV2 from "containers/PageSearch/PageSearchV2";
import MediaRunningContainer from "containers/MediaRunningContainer/MediaRunningContainer";
import PageSingleGallery from "containers/PageSingleGallery/PageSingleGallery";
import PageSingleAudio from "containers/PageSingleAudio/PageSingleAudio";
import PageSingleVideo from "containers/PageSingleVideo/PageSingleVideo";
import PageArchiveVideo from "containers/PageArchive/PageArchiveVideo";
import PageArchiveAudio from "containers/PageArchive/PageArchiveAudio";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

export const pages: Page[] = [
  { path: "/", exact: true, component: PageHome },
  { path: "/#", exact: true, component: PageHome },
  { path: "/archive/:slug", component: PageArchive },
  { path: "/archive-video/:slug", component: PageArchiveVideo },
  { path: "/archive-audio/:slug", component: PageArchiveAudio },
  //
  { path: "/author/:slug", component: PageAuthor },
  { path: "/author-v2/:slug", component: PageAuthorV2 },
  //
  { path: "/single/:slug", component: PageSingleTemp3Sidebar },
  {
    path: "/single-sidebar/:slug",
    component: PageSingleTemplate3,
  },
  {
    path: "/single-template-2/:slug",
    component: PageSingleTemplate2,
  },
  {
    path: "/single-2-sidebar/:slug",
    component: PageSingleTemp2Sidebar,
  },
  {
    path: "/single-template-3/:slug",
    component: PageSingle,
  },
  {
    path: "/single-3-sidebar/:slug",
    component: PageSingleHasSidebar,
  },
  {
    path: "/single-gallery/:slug",
    component: PageSingleGallery,
  },
  {
    path: "/single-audio/:slug",
    component: PageSingleAudio,
  },
  {
    path: "/single-video/:slug",
    component: PageSingleVideo,
  },

  { path: "/search", component: PageSearch },
  { path: "/search-v2", component: PageSearchV2 },
  { path: "/about", component: PageAbout },
  { path: "/contact", component: PageContact },
  { path: "/page404", component: Page404 },
  { path: "/login", component: PageLogin },
  { path: "/signup", component: PageSignUp },
  { path: "/forgot-pass", component: PageForgotPass },
  { path: "/dashboard", component: PageDashboard },
  { path: "/subscription", component: PageSubcription },
  //
  { path: "/home-demo-2", component: PageHomeDemo2 },
  { path: "/home-demo-3", component: PageHomeDemo3 },
  { path: "/home-demo-4", component: PageHomeDemo4 }, 
  //
];

const Routes = () => {
  return ( 
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <ScrollToTop />
        <HeaderContainer />
        <Switch>
          {pages.map(({ component, path, exact }) => {
            return (
              <Route
                key={path}
                component={component}
                exact={!!exact}
                path={path}
              />
            );
          })}
          <Route component={Page404} /> 
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
        {/* MEDIA */}
        <MediaRunningContainer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your design for this is not correct, instead you should be using `RouteComponentProps`for your route components and your entire page shouldn't be connected to redux, otherwise it will rerender the entire page on a change.  For login and things you should be creating an auth route, not passed as props.

You're also exporting your login component as a connection to redux, meaning you're using an HOC wrapper of type `ConnectionComponent` and that route is expecting `ComponentType` and `ConnectionComponent` is not a `ComponentType`.

Something you can try is:

```
interface Props extends RouteComponentProps {
  ...
}
```

However I'm not sure if it will fix your issue.